# how do we track fb users which are Login and Signing up on my portal, since they would be redirected to same page after Login/Signup

Tags: php, facebook, google-analytics, fbsdkloginkit

On our website we are using fb for user login and signup.We have a unique callback url setup in the fb app ex: www.test.com/account/fbLogin.

In this particular function we determine whether the user has registered on our portal and redirect accordingly. Also, the user is redirected to a page from where he clicked the signup/login button and not on a particular page.

From db we can determine whether its a new user or old, but how can we determine through Google Analytics or do things differently in code so we can track these users.

Pls guide me if I'm doing things in a wrong way!

In short the question is: How do we track fb users which are Login and Signing up on my portal, since they would be redirected to same page after Login/Signup.

Comment: Welcome to stack http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask please describe the problem and what **you** have done to solve it.   We are not here to guild you or walk you though implementing something.

Comment: @DalmTo I addressed in the Question itself what I have done, I'm expecting an answer from the audience here. If you could read the statement correctly: I'm asking to correct me incase I'm wrong in implementing the fbLogin functionality. Question is how do we track fb users which are Login and Signing up on my portal, since they would be redirected to same page after Login/Signup

Comment: As it stands this question is probably still too broad to get a useful answer. There are many possible ways to "do things differently in code". Also, please make the title clearer.

Comment: done.. pls check

Comment: @NinadAjnikar If you would like different information from the one I provided in my answer you can comment on it so I can edit it

Answer (score 0):

As I can understand you wish to get some tips for your implementation that uses the facebook signup/login mechanism.

- To track the 'intention' of the user to signin or register from facebook, it would be advise to add a click event on the specific button on your website
- Another thing is to be careful of 'fake' **referral** traffic coming from facebook just from your login mechanism. What I would advise you to do is keep a variable for the user that goes to login/signup to your service through facebook and then when he comes back set his referrer to your site's domain. That way you prevent these fake referrrals.

**As per the authors comments: To track users that have used the fbConnect to signup you can just track this event you can use the event I described in bullet 1 with an action of 'login' or 'signup' depending on the situation. The javascript code will look like this for a login and the action will change for register accordingly.

```
ga('send', 'event','fbConnect', 'login');
```

To track specific user behaviors I would advise doing a [userId](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookies-user-id#user_id) implementation so you can then analyze your data with ease. In that way you could query based on user id and count of specific events for each user at a specific time period. Another way is to use user-scoped [custom dimensions](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets) that will be set based on the login behavior that you want to track.

Comment: I want to track users who are using the fbConnect functionality to login/signup on my portal. I want to specifically track who have signed up using fbConnect and are not logging in using fbConnect.